# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve React-js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve React-js?

ERROR in multi .src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.src/index.js' in 'G:\new-react\reactquiz'
@ multi .src/index.js main[0]

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 .src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.src/index.js' in 'G:\new-react\reactquiz'
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 .src/index.js main[1]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        '.src/index.js'
    ],
    output:{
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app/js/main.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
          { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
          { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                APP
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Comment: It helps to actually read the error message. You wrote `.src` where I think you meant `./src` or simply `src`.

Comment: ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Comment: | ReactDOM.render(
>     <App />,
|     document.getElementById('app')
| );
 @ multi ./src/index.js main[0]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to mention the right path for your src folder.
***`../src`*** or whatever your path is

Comment: ERROR in multi ../src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../src/index.js' in 'G:\new-react\reactquiz\src\components'
 @ multi ../src/index.js main[0]

Comment: ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ../src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../src/index.js' in 'G:\new-react\reactquiz\src\components'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ../src/index.js main[1]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Check below config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output:{
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app/js/main.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
          { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
          { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    }
}
```